# Assigning week for current date as week 0

Tags: sql

I need to write the SQL code for the following logic. Can anyone please help with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJNpJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a Microsoft Power BI approach and just create a calendar table with all the dates.  Then your SQL is just a simple join

```
[ Date ] [ Week ]
10-28-19    44
10-29-19    44
10-30-19    44
10-31-19    44
11-01-19    44
11-02-19    44
11-03-19    44
11-04-19    45
11-05-19    45
.......
```

Comment: can you please me to write the sql code for the logic shared the in image?